# java XMLSerializer avoid Complex Empty Elements

Tags: java, xmlserializer

I've got this code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    DOMImplementation impl = builder.getDOMImplementation();
    Document xmldoc = impl.createDocument(null, null, null);

    Element root = xmldoc.createElement("root");
    Element textElement = xmldoc.createElement("text");
    Text textNode = xmldoc.createTextNode("");
    root.appendChild(textElement);
    textElement.appendChild(textNode);

    OutputFormat of = new OutputFormat("XML","UTF-8",true);
    of.setIndent(1);
    of.setIndenting(true);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(stream, of);
    // As a DOM Serializer
    serializer.asDOMSerializer();
    serializer.serialize(root);

    System.out.println(stream.toString());
```

I get to console this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <text/>
</root>
```

But, I'd like to get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <text></text>
</root>
```

Does anybody know, how to set the XMLSerializer to avoid Complex Empty Elements?
Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you can change that. The both versions are equivalent. Why do you want to avoid complex empty elements?

Comment: My application is a kind of convertor between two applications, which parses files generated by app 1 to an xml file, which in an input to the app 2. But the app 2 doesn't accept this kind of input. Isn't there possibility to set this via doctype or st like that?

Comment: From the point of view of language definition both versions are equivalent, so there is no construct in DTD or XSD to prevent using of empty tags. My opinion is that you should make the app2 accept the input (because it is a valid input so it should be handled) or if do not have access to that app, you can alter the xml string which is returned by app1 (stream.toString()). More exactly, you should look in string for all "<tag/>" patterns and replace them with "<tag></tag>". My opinion is that, for the sake of software stability, you should make app2 accept the input with empty elements

Comment: An app that will not accept `<tag/>` cannot claim to read XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with XMLSerializer not allowing rendering customization of empty tags. My solution was to extend the original XMLSerializer code and override the serializeElement method:

I have copied the original code and changed the closing printing part:

**protected void serializeElement(Element elem) throws IOException**
...

```
if (isSelfClosingElement(elem))
    _printer.printText("/>");
else
_printer.printText("></" + elem.getTagName() + ">");
```

where **isSelfClosingElement** holds a list of self closing elements

**NOTE:** additionally you need to copy the **printAttribute()** and **printNamespaceAttr()** method as it is marked private instead of protected.

Answer (score 3):

**Outcome:** I don't think it is possible. XMLSerializer does not support such configuration.

**Analysis:**
When you call `serializer.serialize(root)`, [BaseMarkupSerializer's serialize(Element)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/xerces/xerces/2.4.0/org/apache/xml/serialize/BaseMarkupSerializer.java#BaseMarkupSerializer.serialize%28org.w3c.dom.Element%29) method is invoked. It defines type of node you pass to serialize and chooses appropriate way to deal with it.

When it comes to the text node, it calls [XMLSerializer's serializeElement(Element)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/xerces/xerces/2.4.0/org/apache/xml/serialize/XMLSerializer.java#XMLSerializer.serializeElement%28org.w3c.dom.Element%29) method:

```
// If element has children, then serialize them, otherwise
// serialize en empty tag.       
if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
    //... irrelevant code...
    endElementIO( null, null, tagName );
} else {
    //... irrelevant code...
    _printer.printText( "/>" ); // <------ HARDCODED, NON-CONFIGURABLE
    //... irrelevant code...
}
```

**Problem:**
As you can see, way of closing empty element is hardcoded and not configurable (if you look for complete code snippet from source code).

**Solution:** 
Since XMLSerializer is not final, you could create your own serializer by extending it and overriding it's method. One of the ways would be changing:

```
_printer.printText( "/>" );
```

to

```
_printer.printText( "</" );
_printer.printText( elem.getTagName() );
_printer.printText( ">" );
```

**Opinion:** 
I am not sure if there is no clean solution and I see this solution as the last resort solution. Anyway, you should look yourself through the sources and/or documentation for more information.

Comment: +1 This is most definitely not possible with the standard Xerces serializer.  It may be possible with other serializers but I don't know offhand of any that do this, and can't find anything on Google either.